# iterate over pandas series and format date

Tags: python, pandas

I need to extract all items from a pandas series is sort I can recreate locally 
in my environment.

When I iterate over the series, the result doesn't allow to recreate it.

When I check the item of the series I get :

```
ser

2016-07-01     0
2016-07-04     1
2016-07-05     2
2016-07-06     3
2016-07-07     4
2016-07-08     5
2016-07-11     6
2016-07-12     7
2016-07-13     8
2016-07-14     9
2016-07-15    10
```

When I iterate over it :

```
for items in ser.iteritems(): 
             print(items)

(Timestamp('2016-07-01 00:00:00'), 0)
(Timestamp('2016-07-04 00:00:00'), 1)
(Timestamp('2016-07-05 00:00:00'), 2)
(Timestamp('2016-07-06 00:00:00'), 3)
(Timestamp('2016-07-07 00:00:00'), 4)
(Timestamp('2016-07-08 00:00:00'), 5)
(Timestamp('2016-07-11 00:00:00'), 6)
(Timestamp('2016-07-12 00:00:00'), 7)
(Timestamp('2016-07-13 00:00:00'), 8)
(Timestamp('2016-07-14 00:00:00'), 9)
(Timestamp('2016-07-15 00:00:00'), 10)
```

I need to have a series (i.e.
`['2016-07-01','2016-07-04'.......''2016-07-15']`) in sort I can assign as a `pd.Series`

Thank you if you can help

Comment: What is the output you want? The dates or the numbers?

Comment: `ser.index.values`?

Comment: Why do you need it as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following `pd.Series`:

```
s=pd.Series(index=['2016-07-01', '2016-07-04','2016-07-05'], data=range(0,3))

2016-07-01    0
2016-07-04    1
2016-07-05    2
```

And your `format_date` function:

```
def format_date(string_date):
    # format your date
    formatted_date = string_date.replace('-','/') #pd.to_datetime(string_date) 
    return formatted_date
```

This code is for you:

```
s = pd.Series(index= s.index.map(format_date), data=s.values)
```

And returns your series with the formatted date at the index:

```
2016/07/01    0
2016/07/04    1
2016/07/05    2
```